# Troubles with Scrapy and libxml2 installation on Windows 10

Tags: python, scrapy

Need to install `Scrapy` but have such error:

Could not find function `xmlCheckVersion` in library `libxml2`. Is `libxml2` installed?

```
error: command 'C:\\Users\\Artur\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Common\\Microsoft\\Visual C++ for Python\\9.0\\VC\\Bin\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

Command:

```
c:\python27\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\artur\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-apae9o\\lxml\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\artur\appdata\local\temp\pip-knhut_-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\artur\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-apae9o\lxml\
```

Tried to install `libxml2` but unfortunately have another error. Try different ways but didn't succeed. Have the same error:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip install libxml2
Collecting libxml2
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement libxml2 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for libxml2
```

I have `python 2.7.11`, `windows 10 64x`.

Comment: It's most likely `lxml` which scrapy depends on. Have you went through the recommendations on [the official docs](http://lxml.de/installation.html#ms-windows) ? Scrapy docs itself [recommend using Anaconda for windows os](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/install.html#anaconda)

Comment: Have successfully installed Scrapy via Anaconda. Thanks for help!